# Update to Precompiled Site

Tags: asp.net

I have a .NET 2.0, precompiled and deployed web site.  I have decompiled the site and added new functionality to a 'dev branch' of the site.  I now need to upgrade the site to .NET 3.5, so that the new features can function, and add the new features to the 'production' site.

How can I go about this merge of features into the 'production' site?  I have several C# classes, new pages, and uncompiled source code for existing pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to deploy the decompiled site under 3.5, but keep most 2.0 decompiled pages, and above all, replace web.config with the 3.5 version.  web.config seldom affects serving of regular (aspx) pages, so replacing it to get 3.5 has very little impact.

Answer (score 1):

If you recompile the new features and thus have a new precompiled site running a new version of .Net there won't be anything to merge unless you don't do a full deployment but if  you don't do a full deployment how can you have upgraded to a new version of .Net?

Comment: I believe you can mix .Net 2.0 and 3.5 but haven't tried it before and my first thought is it doesn't sound like good practice if you could avoid it.

Comment: @Dave, I figure installing 3.5 will be the basis of my upgrading to 3.5.  Unchanged, precomiled pages can remain as they are, as 2.0 code should run fine under 3.5, and I would rather not risk updating these pages.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just recompile the entire site in .NET 3.5, install the 3.5 runtimes onto your target site and just reinstall the newly complied 3.5 version of your website?